# ¿Cómo guardar datos al salir y entrar a app en Android Studio?

Tags: java, android-studio

Soy nuevo en Android studio, lo que tengo programado es un simple botón que al ser pulsado va incrementando un numero de 1 en 1, lo que intento hacer es que si el usuario sale de la app y vuelve a entrar se quede el numero que dejó.
¿Alguna idea?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button btn_click;
   int numero=0;
       TextView CajaDeTexto;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      CajaDeTexto=findViewById(R.id.number);
        btn_click=findViewById(R.id.btn_click);

        btn_click.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
          numero++;
          CajaDeTexto.setText(Integer.toString(numero));

  }

 }
        });
  

    }
```

Comment: Habría varias maneras de hacer esto. Tal vez lo más sencillo en este caso sea utilizar SharedPreferences: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences

Comment: ya pude hacerlo y sí usé  SharePreference, gracias